# debconf-set-selection for openssh-server "disable root login" prompt

Tags: ssh, debian, dpkg, debconf

I'm trying to set up a non-interactive upgrade (Wheezy to Jessie). I get a prompt to disable root login over ssh, and I want to answer "no". Can I preseed that using `debconf-set-selection`?

How can I find out what the conf selection is called? I tried using `debconf-get-selection` and I guess the following four selections are set:

```
root@beaglebone:~# debconf-get-selections | grep ssh
openssh-server  ssh/use_old_init_script boolean true
openssh-server  ssh/vulnerable_host_keys    note    
openssh-server  ssh/disable_cr_auth boolean false
openssh-server  ssh/encrypted_host_key_but_no_keygen    note
```

Are there others available for openssh-server? How do I find out what they are?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, finally found full preseed lists [here](https://preseed.debian.net/debian-preseed)

```
############################
#### openssh-server_6.7p1-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb
############################

### Description: Disable SSH password authentication for root?
#   Previous versions of openssh-server permitted logging in as root over SSH
#   using password authentication. The default for new installations is now
#   "PermitRootLogin without-password", which disables password authentication
#   for root without breaking systems that have explicitly configured SSH
#   public key authentication for root.
#   .
#   This change makes systems more secure against brute-force password
#   dictionary attacks on the root user (a very common target for such
#   attacks). However, it may break systems that are set up with the
#   expectation of being able to SSH as root using password authentication. You
#   should only make this change if you do not need to do that.
# d-i openssh-server/permit-root-login boolean false
```